# Дата некорректно вносится в датафрейм r

Tags: парсер, дата, r

По заданию написал парсер, который берёт дату с сайта по дням недели. Например, понедельник и вторник 18.10.2021 и 19.10.2021 года соответственно. Далее применяю к нему функцию asDate с нужным форматом и получаю тип данных "Дата". Потом пытаюсь это всё добавить в датафрейм, но он вообще какую-то глупость показывает. При любых изменениях в `fulldf[nrow(fulldf) + 1,]` rmd'шка вообще не собирается. При этом всевозможные проверки показывают что у переменной нужный тип данных и, при этом, дата правильно отображается.

```
monday <- as.Date(monday, format="%d.%m.%Y")
tuesday <- as.Date(tuesday, format="%d.%m.%Y")
print(monday)
print(tuesday)
class(monday)
fulldf <- data.frame(Audience = "", Status = "", StartDate = "", EndDate = "")
fulldf[nrow(fulldf) + 1,] = list(pos[1], name[1], date(monday), tuesday)
print(fulldf)
```

[image: monday & tuesday]

[image: class(monday)]

[image: Результат]

Answer (score 0):

Дату в списке нужно явно задавать

```
fulldf[nrow(fulldf) + 1,] = list(pos[1], name[1],format.Date(monday,
 "%d.%m.%Y"),format.Date(tuesday, "%d.%m.%Y"))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]